# how can we write a program that can allow us to input as many string as we want?

Tags: c

I want my program to ask me the number of strings that I want to input

for e.g  input screen   :    3          \ number of strings

```
abcndhfk     \\ string1
snsjdmsk     \\ string2
dsdnfnkd     \\ string3
```

my bad code in c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{   
    int n;
    char str[1000];

    scanf("%d\n", &n);

    for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%s\n", str[i]);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Post the code and where you are stuck?

Comment: And pick a language.

Comment: using a 2d char array and `malloc()` should work take user input then allocate the space based on that

Comment: `int i=1` -- make that `int i = 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_STRING_COUNT 1000
#define MAX_STRING_LENGTH 100

int main()
{
    int n;
    char str[MAX_STRING_COUNT][MAX_STRING_LENGTH];
    int ret = scanf("%d\n",&n);
    if (ret != 1 || n < 0 || n > MAX_STRING_COUNT) {
        puts("Wrong number of strings!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        ret = fgets(str[i], MAX_STRING_LENGTH, stdin);
        if (ret == NULL) {
            puts("Error reading string\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Never read unbound strings**. That may cause an overflow, that is security flow in your program.

Comment: `scanf` does not necessarily cause overflows. You can put a maximum width in, just like for `fgets`.

Comment: Why not use malloc for every new string needed.

Comment: @chris that's why I said "unbound strings".

Comment: I don't see how `fgets` works any better for unbound strings. Unless you just mean not passing in a length (which `fgets` enforces). In that case, you might as well just say not to read unbound strings period.

Comment: @Igor because using array is simpler. OP doesn't know how to read a couple of string; I don't want to overwhelm him with dynamic memory.

Comment: +1 Agree about "unbound strings".  Minor: using `int` for `i,n` when `size_t` is best is a potential security flaw - but you do have a good `n < 0 || n > MAX_STRING_COUNT`

Comment: `int` is guaranteed to contain `10000` in its range.

Comment: @chux `size_t` is unsigned; that's why I can't read `n` as `size_t`. If user enters negative number, scan returns no errors and `n` becomes huge positive number (just checked). While `n > MAX_STRING_COUNT` should handle that, I don't think it's a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You've tagged this with C++ so I assume you can use C++ for this solution.

If so, you can use `std::cin` and `std::string`:

```
int main() {
   int n;
   std::string s;

   cout << "How many strings do you want to enter?" << std::endl;

   // Get the user input and store it in n
   cin >> n;

   // Ask for a string n times
   for (int x = 0; x < n; x++) {
      cout << "Enter a string:" << std::endl;

      // Get the user input string and put it in s
      cin >> s;

      // Do something with the string here
   }
   return 0;
}
```

You'll want to do error checking and I haven't included the headers you need, but this is the core of the procedure.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    char str[n][1000];

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        scanf("%999s", str[i]);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("%s\n", str[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```